# Why I receive ModuleNotFoundError while testing using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I use `pytest` for unit testing, but I received this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

when I import two modules locally:

```py
from package import module1
from package import module2
```

The current working directory looks like this:

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── test-requirements.txt
└── tests
    ├── test_module1.py
    ├── test_module2.py
```

Comment: From which directory do you run `pytest`?

Comment: At the same level of the current working directory that I shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `python -m pytest` or install your project with `pip install .`. The reason that it does not work with `pytest` directly is that the current working directory won't be appended to `sys.path` in that case, i.e., your project is not visible.